# C++ Templates variadic but static

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am training my template skills in C++ and want to implement a vector class.
The class is defined by the vector dimension N and the type T.
Now I would like to have a constructor that takes exactly N variables of type T.
However I can't get my head around how to tell the variadic template to only accept N parameters. Maybe this is possible with template specialization?
Or am I thinking in the wrong direction?
Any thoughts/ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.

**More thoughts**

All examples on variadic templates I already saw used recursion to "iterate" through the parameter list. However I have in mind that <strike>constructors can not be called from constructors</strike> (read the comments in the answer). So maybe it is not even possible to use variadic templates in constructors? Anyway that would only defer me to the usage of a factory function with the same basic problem.

Comment: Well, I think that Luc Danton answered before your edit, so where did it came from?

Comment: @Griwes: Yes indeed, what do you mean with 'where did it came from'?

Comment: @Griwes: Now I understand what you mean^^ I revised my wording several times, so I started editing before I saw his post but finished after him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A variadic constructor seems appropriate:

```
template<typename T, int Size>
struct vector {
    template<typename... U>
    explicit
    vector(U&&... u)
        : data {{ std::forward<U>(u)... }}
    {
        static_assert( sizeof...(U) == Size, "Wrong number of arguments provided" );
    }

    T data[Size];
};
```

This example uses perfect forwarding and and `static_assert` to generate a hard-error if not exactly `Size` arguments are passed to the constructor. This can be tweaked:

- you can turn the hard-error into a soft-error by using `std::enable_if` (triggering SFINAE); I wouldn't recommend it
- you can change the condition to be `sizeof...(U) <= Size`, letting the remaining elements to be value initialized
- you can require that the types passed to the constructor are convertible to `T`, or exactly match e.g. `T const&`; either turning a violation into a hard-error (using `static_assert` again) or a soft-error (SFINAE again)

Comment: Very nice I did not think of the initialization via list. That solves the recursion problem if there is one. So is there one? ^^ @Nim: He already used T for another type, so it is only logic to take it's successor as next typename.

Comment: @Nim `U` is a template parameter to the constructor (which is a member template of a template). Using `T` would mean shadowing the template parameter of `vector` and is not allowed.

Comment: @Nobody Constructors can call other constructors in C++11 (this feature is called 'delegating constructors'; look for it on e.g. SO to learn more), you could recurse with those (but I think a variadic helper could suffice here). Note that not many compilers support it that feature yet. I wouldn't recommend recursion as recursively constructing an array is awkward.

Comment: Of course there is no more recursion, that is what I meant :) As to your last point: Are there any additional steps that have to be taken to allow types that can be converted to T as arguments or does this just follow from the default typechecking?

Comment: @Nobody Right now the use of perfect forwarding means that if `T` is constructible from `U` (for all `U`) then all goes well, otherwise you get a soft error. Using `static_assert` would mean you can use your own error message, and would make it a hard error instead. All of this is at compile-time.